# ASP MVC field validation inside EditorFor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a form with and one of the fields for the model is complex, so I created a custom editor for that field.
Here is the part of the editor in the main form:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-3 control-label">@i18n.Translations</label>
    <div class="control-group col-md-9">
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Translations)
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the Custom Editor:

```
@using XXX.i18n
@using XXX.ViewModels
@model XXX.ViewModels.ServiceTranslation

@{
  bool translationNameValid = Html.ViewData.ModelState.IsValidField(Html.IdFor(m => m.TranslationName).ToString());
  bool translationDescriptionValid = Html.ViewData.ModelState.IsValidField(Html.IdFor(m => m.TranslationDescription).ToString());
}

<div class="form-group">
  @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.EntityLanguageId)
  @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Language)
  @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.TranslationId.Left)
  @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.TranslationId.Right)
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="input-group @(translationNameValid ? null : "state-error")">
      <span class="input-group-addon">@Model.Language</span>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.TranslationName, new { @placeholder = i18n.Name, @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
    <div class="@(translationNameValid ? null : "state-error")">
      <em for="@Html.IdFor(m => m.TranslationName)" class="invalid">@Html.ValidationMessage("TranslationName")</em>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 @(translationDescriptionValid ? null : "state-error")">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.TranslationDescription, new { @placeholder = i18n.Description, @class = "form-control" })
    <em for="@Html.IdFor(m => m.TranslationDescription)" class="invalid">@Html.ValidationMessage("TranslationDescription")</em>
  </div>
</div>
```

Also, I should mention that the main form is inside a partial and the `TranslationName` and `TranslationDescription` are 2 required fields (and are annotated with `[Required]` in the ViewModel)
The `@Html.ValidationMessage` return the required field message with the textboxes are empty.

My problem is that the `translationDescriptionValid` and the `translationNameValid` are always true and they should return false when the fields are blank.
I've used this method in other forms with success.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What is the purpose of `bool translationNameValid = Html.ViewData.ModelState.IsValidField(Html.IdFor(m => m.TranslationName).ToString());`?

Comment: I'm using it here `@(translationNameValid ? null : "state-error")` to print the class, in case the field is invalid.
I'm using bootstrap.